# woocommerce subscription plugin is not working with group product

Tags: woocommerce

I have install woo commerce subscription and woocommerce plugin. I added one simple subscription product. Now I want to link to a group product, but the linked group product option is not available.

Comment: Do not understand what you are asking. Please try to re-phrase it.

Comment: is it possible to simple subscription product linked with group product in woocommerce plugin.And another thing is i want to add more than one simple subscription product in group product.please help me how is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

To create a grouped product you must assign the child product's to the group product parent. Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JKZp0QWX0Y) on how to create a grouped product.

Assuming you have all your products created already. Go to your subscription product, go to the "linked products" part of the product data metabox and under "Grouping" select the grouped product you wish the subscription to be a part of.

[image]